# how to add a tag to the navigation tabs displayed in moodle profile page

Tags: php, moodle

I want to add a new tab to the navigation of profile page. I hope to do this by using moodle block or module. Please give me a clue to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to hack the code in `/user/tabs.php` (Moodle 1.9).

Just add a new element to  the `$toprow` array:

```
$toprow[] = new tabobject('extra', 'http://a_link', 'Extra');
```

Where I'm specifying an id, a link and a label for the new tab. Obviously, you have to add the code to manage the content of the tab (possibly using `$filterselect`). In the above file, this is done for all other tabs, so just use that as a template.

For the parameters of the tabobject constructor, refer to `/htdocs/lib/weblib.php`.

The truth is in the code.